# Insert static html in Jinja2 template in CKAN

Tags: html, static, jinja2, ckan

I am very new to html, jinja2, templates, and making websites in general, but my employer asked me to do this job, commissioned externally, so I am trying my best.

I am building a website in the CKAN framework, which uses Jinja2 for templating.
On some pages our customer asks to include a static .html file (provided by them). The file has to be rendered, i.e. not show the raw code.
The final page will have to look like this:

[image: structure of the page]

The "outer part" is handled by Jinja2 and follows a predefined layout and template equal for all pages. The "internal box" must instead render the custom .html file provided by the customer (different file for each page).

With the idea of fetching the correct name for the custom .html file in some way in the future, I am for now trying just to have *an* .html file appear.
I have already tried with adding a block to the template like

```
{% block static_html_desc %}
    <script type="text/html", src="my_file.html">>/script>
{% endblock %}
```

but this produces nothing (i.e. there is just white space in the spot where this is supposed to render).
Then I have tried with

```
{% block static_html_desc %}
    {# include 'my_file.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

which sorta works, meaning that `my_file.html` gets rendered only if the file itself is inside the `/templates/` folder, otherwise jinja crashes with "no template found" error.
Given that this file is not dynamic, it feels wrong to put it in the templates folder; there will be several such files, so it's also more logical to keep them in the public folder and have my jinja2 template pull from there.

As said, I am quit a beginner in this so any help and details are greatly appreciated with either Jinja2 or CKAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good answer myself, posting here in case others are wondering the same.

The following is based on the excellent tutorial at W3School: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

I created a javascript file `custom_include_html.js`, and placed it in the `/templates` folder of my CKAN plugin. (I reckon it is not a template file, but it relates directly to templates and at current I am not bothered with changing the jinja2 loader path, so I am fine with it staying in that folder).
The content of the file is the following, copied from the W3School tutorial but posted here for your own reference:

```
function includeHTML() {
    var x, i, elem, file, xhttp;
    z = document.getElementByTagName("*");
    for (i=0; i<z.length; i++) {
        elem = z[i];
        file = elem.getAttribute("custom-include-html");
        if (file) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readystate == 4) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {elem.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
                    if (this.status == 400) {elem.innerHTML = "Page not found, sorry."}
                    elem.removeAttribute("custom-include-html");
                    includeHTML();
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
            xhttp.send();
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

Then, in the Jinja2 template defining the page I have to insert the `my_file.html` file into, I made a block as

```
{% block static_html_desc %}
    <div custom-include-html="/my_file.html"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Note that **this file is placed in CKAN's public folder**, exactly as I wanted in my question above.

At the bottom of the template, I call the javascript script as:

```
{% block custom_javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">

        {% include custom_include_html.js" %}

        includeHTML();

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The file `my_file.html` gets then rendered in the `{% block static_html_desc %}` block.

At this point, one only has to substitute the call to `my_file.html` with something not hardcoded, so that different pages load the corresponding `*.html` files. This is easly done with the templates helper functions.

Comment: Glad you got something working but if you're using CKAN and customizing it's pages I would really suggest you look at the CKAN docs for Theming. Anyone coming in after you to make updates and is used to CKAN may not expect this.  You could possibly do this with a custom snippet or extending a template. https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/index.html

Comment: Yes sure, I am doing that. The template I am talking about above, extends the existing CKAN template through a plugin I wrote. I didn't emphasize this in my original post or answer; I thought it was not necessary, but that's surely the way to go.